# use RemoteAttribute in modelview for Edit and Create Action

Tags: validation, asp.net-core, attributes

i use RemoteAttribute in my modelview for Check Instantly If Username Exists .

```
[Remote("ValidUsername","UsersManagement",ErrorMessage ="this usernaem is duplicate")]
 public string Username { get; set; }
```

This idea is useful when inserting a new record, but prevents the update from being edited. because the usernaem is exists. What is the solution to that proposal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1 - Use Additional fields:**

You can use the [AdditionalFields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2#remote-attribute) argument to your remote validation attribute in your model and combine that with a hidden field in your view .

In your model class :

```
[Remote("ValidUsername", "Home", ErrorMessage = "this usernaem is duplicate", AdditionalFields = "PageType")]
public string Username { get; set; }
```

In your edit/create page , add hidden field inside the same form as the field your are validating :

```
<label asp-for="Username">Username</label>
<input asp-for="Username" />
<span asp-validation-for="Username"></span>
<input type="hidden" name="PageType" value="Edit" />
```

Then on server side validation , you could get the Additional value(edit/create) and validate base on that , if it is `edit` ,just skip the validation :

```
[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
public IActionResult ValidUsername(string Username, string PageType)
{
    if ("Edit".Equals(PageType))
    {
        return Json(true);
    }
    if (Username.Equals("21"))
    {


        return Json(false);
    }

    return Json(true);
}
```

**Option 2 - Use different view model**

You can also use different view model in create and edit pages.